# upload photo from ipad / get file in file upload control from ipad

Tags: ipad

we have requirement of uploading photo from ipad to website. such that;

[Website page will be opened in safari browser]

ipad user will take his/her snap and it sould get uploaded from ipad to website as a part of registration process.

How can we access the location where the captured photo (image) is getting stored, access that location to upload photo.

is there any javascript

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Apple's sand boxing of apps for security reasons this is not possible. Unless you jail break it, you will not, and can not, access the file system.

Comment: I don't get it with Apple. Why do they want to annoy their users more and more? I know, they want to have us all build "Apps" for their AppStore, but seriously, BASIC HTML forms ought to function/behave normally. Thats why its called a BROWERS. FFs. Stop acting so childish Apple. We want Steve Jobs back.

Comment: Yes, apple doesn't benefit from working browser applications - what they want are native apps. But Steve Jobs is responsible for apples aggressive marketing strategy too.

Comment: I agree, but at least he was right regarding Flash and other plugins. We dont need them in new moderne HTML. Lets work for a better HTML standard and less "patches" from plugins.